# PHP, PDO SQL server, the leading 0 number is cut from the return data

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, slim

I'm working on PHP + Slim Framework. I have to migrate MySQL to SQL Server.
There is something wrong with the return result from SELECT statement.
Here is my example data,

```
╔════╦═══════╦════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ id ║item_id║    lat     ║     lng    ║       timestamp       ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║  1 ║  1    ║51.42743450 ║-0.72776696 ║2017-07-05 09:54:49.000║
║  2 ║  1    ║51.59665507 ║-0.72777098 ║2017-07-05 11:54:49.000║
║  3 ║  2    ║51.59664690 ║-0.67272032 ║2016-08-10 10:11:49.000║
║  4 ║  2    ║51.59664874 ║-0.67270288 ║2016-08-10 11:05:49.000║
║  5 ║  2    ║51.59665167 ║-0.67271587 ║2016-08-10 10:08:49.000║
╚════╩═══════╩════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

And here is the code,

```
public function test(Request  $request, Response  $response, $args)
{
  $query = 'SELECT item_id, lat, lng FROM mySchema.record WHERE item_id = 1';
  $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
  $sth->execute();
  $rows = $sth->fetchAll();
  $data = array('data' => $rows);
  return $response->withJson($data);
}
```

Previously, in MySQL, the data is returned correctly like this (example),

```
"data" : [
    {
        "item_id" : "1",
        "lat" : "51.42743450",
        "lng" : "-0.72776696"
    }
]
```

But after working with SQL Server, it returns data to me like this (example),

```
 "data" : [
    {
        "item_id" : "1",
        "lat" : "51.42743450",
        "lng" : "-.72776696"
    }
]
```

It can be seen that **the leading 0 number is cut from the lng**. I really have no idea how to fix it. Could someone help? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT : Lng datatype is DECIMAL(11,8) in SQL Server which is same as MySQL

#### Update

There is a workaround - to directly add `0` to the data through `sprintf()`. But the problem will not be fixed at the root cause if I go this way. However, I will go this way while there is no proper solution yet.

Comment: How did you define the Data-Field?

Comment: lng is DECIMAL(11,8). Same as the MySQL. @Bernhard

Comment: What is the output of $sth->fetchAll()? Just to be sure nothing happends on its way through your function calls.

Comment: @Araw I use print_r() to see it. it's same.

Comment: It works normally if I execute it directly. But PDO + sqlsrv might cause something to the data.

Comment: does anything break?  i mean, the leading zero is not a significant digit, and `-.72` is really the same value as `-0.72`. Does the consumer of the json fail trying to read without the leading zero?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/541935/sql-server-native-client-omitting-leading-zero-in-decimal-when-used-by-sql-server-driver-for-php-1-1) in a native client driver, unfotunately I have no evidence it has been ever corrected. Try to return the [value as NVARCHAR](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6cc6d0b4-4aec-4f29-9fa5-ad88417a6a30/driver-omitting-leading-zero-in-decimal?forum=sqldriverforphp)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a little late but this has been solved with a parametrization. [Here's the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/formatting-decimals-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver16).

Short answer: set `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FORMAT_DECIMALS` parameter to `true`.